# How to see the table just modified in a script with Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've this block in sql developer:

```
begin
 delete from temp;
 insert into temp values (1);
 dbms_output.put_line('Done');
end;
```

If I hit F5 the script runs fine. The table is updated with the value 1 and the "Script output" tab says 'Done'.

However I would like to automatically visualize the table that I have just modified in the "result" tab after I execute the block. Is that possible? How?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CURSOR:

```
declare 
a temp.id%type; --name column in your table
cursor c1 is
select id from temp;
begin
  delete from temp;
  insert into temp values (1);
  open c1;
  loop 
  fetch c1 into a;
  dbms_output.put_line (a);
  exit when c1%notfound;
  end loop;
  CLOSE C1;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working. I modified just a bit your code putting <exit when c1%notfound;> before dbms_output to avoid to print a line where nothing is found.

Comment: @starko CLOSE C1; statement is missing in your code .

Answer (score 2):

No need of any anonymous **PL/SQL** block. Just run the **SQL** statements as a script,

```
delete from temp;
insert into temp values (1);
select * from temp;
```

Put the above three statements in **SQL Developer** worksheet and then press **F5** to run as a script, see the output in the Script output tab. You must finally **COMMIT** to make the table changes permanent.

You cannot do `select * from table` in PL/SQL as it is a pure SQL statement. PL/SQL expects an INTO clause. Never do in PL/SQL when you could do the same in pure SQL.

But, if you really want to do it in a `BEGIN-END` block, then put the SELECT statement outside the PL/SQL block. Do not merge PL/SQL and SQL.

```
begin
 delete from temp;
 insert into temp values (1);
 dbms_output.put_line('Done');
end;
/
select * from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will also work, when the table is filled and you do not use the delete.

```
declare 
    a temp.id%type; --name column in your table
begin
    -- delete from temp;
    insert into temp values (1)
    returning id into a;
    dbms_output.put_line (a);
    dbms_output.put_line('Done');
end;
```